# How to add declared values to SELECT statement SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

The following code works with no errors but gives the wrong value as I require `attackPercentage`, `safetyPercentage` and `consistencyPercentage` simply be passed back and not have any conditions applied after they have been set. So I don't require..

```
WHERE @raterAccountID = raterAccountID
```

for `attackPercentage`, `safetyPercentage` and `consistencyPercentage`

The values set by the `SET` statements are what I require. I just didn't know how to put `attackPercentage`, `safetyPercentage` and `consistencyPercentage` in the `SELECT` statement so that they are passed to the reader in VB.

`attackPercentage`, `safetyPercentage` and `consistencyPercentage` are the players actual overall ratings calculated from what users have voted.

`attack`, `safety` and `consistency` are what the rater has vote.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectPlayersRating]
    @playerAccountID uniqueidentifier,
    @raterAccountID uniqueidentifier
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @attackPercentage INT, @safetyPercentage INT,  @consistencyPercentage INT

    SET @attackPercentage = (SELECT SUM(attack) 
                             FROM tblRatings 
                             WHERE @playerAccountID = playerAccountID) /
                            (SELECT COUNT(attack) 
                             FROM tblRatings 
                             WHERE @playerAccountID = playerAccountID)

    SET @safetyPercentage = (SELECT SUM(safety) 
                             FROM tblRatings 
                             WHERE @playerAccountID = playerAccountID) / 
                            (SELECT COUNT(safety) 
                              FROM tblRatings 
                              WHERE @playerAccountID = playerAccountID)

    SET @consistencyPercentage = (SELECT SUM(consistency) 
                                  FROM tblRatings 
                                  WHERE @playerAccountID = playerAccountID) /
                                 (SELECT COUNT(consistency) 
                                  FROM tblRatings 
                                  WHERE @playerAccountID = playerAccountID)

    SELECT 
        attack, safety, consistency, 
        @attackPercentage AS attackPercentage, 
        @safetyPercentage AS safetyPercentage, 
        @consistencyPercentage AS consistencyPercentage 
    FROM
        tblRatings 
    WHERE 
        @playerAccountID = playerAccountID 
        AND @raterAccountID = raterAccountID
END
```

```
    Dim DBConnect4 As New DBConn
    Using db As DbConnection = DBConnect4.Conn("DBConnectionString")
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = DBConnect4.Command(db, "SelectPlayersRating")
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("playerAccountID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier, ParameterDirection.Input)).Value = Guid.Parse(Request.QueryString("aID"))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("raterAccountID", SqlDbType.Uniqueidentifier, ParameterDirection.Input)).Value = acc.accountID
        db.Open()
        Dim DR As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
        While DR.Read
            ddlAttack.SelectedValue=DR("attack")
            ddlSafety.SelectedValue=DR("safety")
            ddlConsistency.SelectedValue=DR("consistency")
            Dim attack As Integer = DR("attackPercentage")
            Dim safety As Integer = DR("safetyPercentage")
            Dim consistency As Integer = DR("consistencyPercentage")
            Me.attack.Attributes("data-cp-percentage")=attack
            Me.safety.Attributes("data-cp-percentage")=safety
            Me.consistency.Attributes("data-cp-percentage")=consistency
            Me.overall.Attributes("data-cp-percentage")=(attack+safety+consistency)/3
        End While
        DR.Close()
        DR = Nothing
        cmd.Dispose()
        cmd = Nothing
        db.Dispose()
        db.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Please provide some text example of how the data are and what you want to see.

Comment: Aren't all those averages? Why not use `SELECT AVG(attack) as attack ... from tblRatings where ....` ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Repeat the averages on every row for the same player?

Comment: I've updated question as I don't think I was too clear.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in a single `SELECT`.

**Please note:**

1. If the fields are of type `int` you will need to add before each `/`: `* 1.0 /`.
2. If the fields are not nullable, you can replace `COUNT(attack)` etc with `COUNT(*)`

*EDIT: I think you actually want the percentage of the total. In which case see further answer below*

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectPlayersRating]
@playerAccountID uniqueidentifier,
@raterAccountID uniqueidentifier
AS

SELECT
    attack = SUM(attack) / COUNT(attack),
    safety = SUM(safety) / COUNT(safety),
    consistency = SUM(consistency) / COUNT(consistency)
FROM tblRatings
WHERE @playerAccountID = playerAccountID AND @raterAccountID <> raterAccountID;
```

---

Answer for percentage of total:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectPlayersRating]
@playerAccountID uniqueidentifier,
@raterAccountID uniqueidentifier
AS

SELECT
    t.attack,
    t.safety,
    t.consistency,
    totals.*
FROM tblRatings t
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT
        attackPercentage = SUM(attack) / COUNT(attack),
        safetyPercentage = SUM(safety) / COUNT(safety),
        consistencyPercentage = SUM(consistency) / COUNT(consistency)
    FROM tblRatings
    WHERE @playerAccountID = playerAccountID
) totals
WHERE @playerAccountID = playerAccountID AND @raterAccountID = raterAccountID;
```

Comment: Just trying to get it to work but its giving me errors: 
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

Comment: Your code does the same as mine. I'm not struggling with sorting the percentages out etc. It is the `@raterAccountID = raterAccountID` part that is causing problems. I need to `SELECT attack, safety, consistency FROM  tblRatings WHERE @playerAccountID = playerAccountID  AND @raterAccountID = raterAccountID` That part is correct. But I also need to `SELECT attackPercentage, safetyPercentage and consistencyPercentage FROM  tblRatings WHERE @playerAccountID = playerAccountID` without the `@raterAccountID = raterAccountID` part. I need this in one SELECT statement and it should work my VB code.

Comment: Still not clear: you want that second result rolled up and averaged, or you want every row cross joined with the original resultset?

Comment: Go back to my original code. It works, but only selects results for `@attackPercentage`, `@safetyPercentage` and `@consistencyPercentage` where `raterAccountID`=`raterAccountID`. I don't want the last condition of `raterAccountID=raterAccount`. I simply want it to send the values I've set back o the reader but I didn't kow how to fit them in to the existing SELECT statement.

Comment: And this query gives you the correct results now? Or do you want it as two separate resultsets / `SELECT`s (which is how I would do it, but I wanted to match your design)

Comment: I've split it in to 2 selects and it is now working. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the real question is how to display averages on each row for a specific player. `SUM(attack)/COUNT(attack)` can be replaced with `AVG(attack)`  etc.

To display aggregate values on each detail row, one can use the `OVER` clause, eg :

```
SELECT
    attack, safety, consistency
    AVG(attack) OVER(PARTITION BY playerAccountiD) as attackPercentage,
    AVG(safety) OVER(PARTITION BY playerAccountiD) as safetyPercentage,
    AVG(consistency) OVER(PARTITION BY playerAccountiD) as consistencyPercentage
FROM tblRatings
WHERE @playerAccountID = playerAccountID AND @raterAccountID <> raterAccountID;
```

The OVER clause calculates the aggregate only over the set of data specified in the `PARTITION BY` clause